# I want to know more artists/musics instrumental like a song "Call of Ktulu" (Metallica)

Tags: similar-artists, instrumental, metal

I want to listen more instrumental metal, like [*The Call of Ktulu*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ride_the_Lightning#The_Call_of_Ktulu) and [*Orion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Puppets#Track_listing)) (Metallica), or [*Into the Lungs of Hell*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_Far,_So_Good..._So_What!#Track_listing) (Megadeth).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Instrumental Thrash Metal. Other good music: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thm5l3Cefrg (The Mask of Insanity - Dunkell Reiter, Thrash Metal band from Brazil).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Band with at least one instrumental song:

- **Ne Obliviscaris** - [*Forget Not (Portal Of I)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsh9xzTCFRk)
- **Gojira** -  [*Dawn*](https://youtu.be/ZFs1hwd4huo)
- **Death** - [*Voice Of The Soul*](https://youtu.be/iOsIXpDH_R0)
- **Death** - [*Cosmic Sea*](https://youtu.be/qJkkU6Oj6Bo)
- **Obscura** - [*A Transcendental Serenade*](https://youtu.be/pEsgYzK7q4A)
- **Hacride** - [*Polarity*](https://youtu.be/4v-hb2Lw5Z0)
- **Opeth** - [A short list](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110405172902AAqhXlz)
- **Persefone** - [*Zazen Meditation*](https://youtu.be/2MQT7nHgePA)
- **Dream Theater** - [All their instrumental song!](https://youtu.be/FK-AWdR7dzg)
- **Sepultura** - [*Inquisition Symphony*](https://youtu.be/Yg0XC9BqWww)
- **Arch Enemy** - [*Enter The Machine*](https://youtu.be/Algzp02MO34)
- **Iced Earth** - [*1776*](https://youtu.be/yD47NIcdmAA)
- **Iron Maiden** - [*Transylvania*](https://youtu.be/GY0RZriJ3gk)
- **Cradle of Filth** - [*Rise of the Pentagram*](https://youtu.be/vRZSE0ZIcyY)
- **Lamb Of God** - [*Ashes Of The Weak*](https://youtu.be/VPf8BR7YYkw)
- **In Flames** - [*Man Made God*](https://youtu.be/PCqfKmJ5xZo)
- **In Flames** - [*Dialogue With Stars*](https://youtu.be/po1_lRHCeTU)
- **Between The Buried And Me** - [*Viridian*](https://youtu.be/tbb2AvqmhLQ)
- **Insomnium** - [*The Gale*](https://youtu.be/onX5b4F7_k4)
- **Be'lakor** - [*Husks*](https://youtu.be/cU6ul3XE92U)
- **Omnium Gatherum** - [*Song For December*](https://youtu.be/CT_vu-glNjE)
- **Dark Tranquillity** - [*Ex Nihilo*](https://youtu.be/dLNWUv_5z1c)
- **Cynic** - [*Textures*](https://youtu.be/GEo8IrU5MQk)
- **Trepalium** - [*Raining Past*](https://youtu.be/LHpHANoj6Og)

Instrumental band:

- **Animals As Leaders** (ex: [*Physical Education*](https://youtu.be/0jpOBd949O4))
- **Scale The Summit** (ex: [*Odyssey*](https://youtu.be/NXpq6XZDRBI))
- **Gru** (ex: [*Nebula*](https://youtu.be/t_7o2ju6j0g))
- **Exivious** (ex: [*Deeply Wooven*](https://youtu.be/hkaLwZePdKM) )
- **Caspian** (ex : [*Of Foam And Wave*](https://youtu.be/2pgwZuXLaW8))
- **An Endless Sporadic** - (ex: [*Spaceship Factory*](https://youtu.be/jCe8NcS3yBs))

I'll complete this list when a new song will come to my mind!

Comment: One more: Musical Death (A Dirge) - Testament

Answer (score 3):

While not really the same genre, try Pelican. All their songs are instrumental, but they're not as metal as the songs of your example. I came to think of them when I thought of Call of Cthulu though for some reason, maybe due to the epic nature of their songs.

Coroner is a band that started out very metal though, and continued to progress, in the true sense of the word. Check out Arc-lite from Punishment from Decadence which is instrumental. It's not as epic as your example tracks though.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on just how metal you want your metal to be, An Endless Sporadic are great instrumental musicians, with elements of prog, metal, alternative, and more.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for instrumental Metal, any of the "Neo-Classical" genre fits that bill.  Yngwie Malmsteen, Vinnie Moore, Tony MacAlpine, Greg Howe, et al.  But this tune rocks starting around 1:00:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbswGkgzHrc

Comment: I would say that Call of Cthulu isn't exactly neo-classical shred...

Answer (score 0):

You can try some Mekong Delta albums:
Classics (1993)
Visions Fugitives (1994)
Pictures at an Exhibition (1996)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mekong_Delta_(band)